# Create PostgreSQL view where column value maps to different name

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I have the following table `items`. which looks like this

```
|    date    |  id | type | qty  | fee |
+------------+-----+------+------+------+
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB04 |  500 |    2 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | CB03 | 1500 |    3 |
| 2015-01-01 | 003 | CB04 |  500 |    1 |
| 2015-01-01 | 004 | CB04 |  100 |    5 |
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB02 |  800 |    6 |
| 2015-01-02 | 002 | CB03 | 3100 |    1 |
|            |     |      |      |      |
```

I want to apply the following is the mapping columen value mapping and create a view on the fly

```
CB04 - aaple
CB03 - orange
CB02 - lime
```

I want to create a view or query, so that the result looks like this.

```
|    date    |  id | type |  name  | qty  | fee |
+------------+-----+------+--------+------+-----+
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB04 | aaple  |  500 |   2 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | CB03 | orange | 1500 |   3 |
| 2015-01-01 | 003 | CB04 | aaple  |  500 |   1 |
| 2015-01-01 | 004 | CB04 | aaple  |  100 |   5 |
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | CB02 | lime   |  800 |   6 |
| 2015-01-02 | 002 | CB03 | orange | 3100 |   1 |
|            |     |      |        |      |     |
```

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I would have used the inner join if it were a table. The mapping is not a table. and depending on the name of the `view` the mapping value changes.

Comment: . . Then your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You can create function for mapping or simply use CASE statement like that:

```
SELECT
(CASE 
 WHEN type ='CB04' THEN 'aaple'
 WHEN type ='CB03' THEN 'orange'
 WHEN type ='CB02' THEN 'lime'
 ELSE 'wrong value' 
END)
FROM items;
```

More about CASE statement:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE